# Output blocks of text in C

Tags: c

I have a large character array `data` and I am wanting to output it to the terminal 30 lines at a time. So I decided to count the characters between each set of 30 new line characters, so I could offset `strncpy` by that much. However when I go to print it out, I get no output. There must be something small but I can't see what's wrong.

```
char* data;
int blocks[100], block_sizes[100];
int traversed, block_idx, nl_chars, i, len, chars;
char* block;

// Determine output blocks
nl_chars = 0;
block_idx = 1;
blocks[0] = 0;
chars = 0;
len = strlen(data);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    chars++;
    if (data[i] == '\n') {
        nl_chars++;
    }

    if (data[i] == '\0' || nl_chars == 30) {
        blocks[block_idx] = i;
        block_sizes[block_idx - 1] = chars;
        block_idx++;
        nl_chars = 0;
        chars = 0;
    }
}

// Output blocks to stdout
traversed = 0;
while (traversed < block_idx) {
    block = malloc(block_sizes[traversed] * sizeof(char));
    if (block == NULL) {
        error("[-]Unable to allocate required memory");
    }
    strncpy(block, data + blocks[traversed], block_sizes[traversed]);
    printf("%s", block);
    free(block);

    while (1) {
        memset(input, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        if (input[0] == '\n' || input[0] == '\r') {
            break;
        }
    }

    traversed++;
}
```

Comment: `i <= len` as you want to deal with the terminating `\0` inside the loop. And better let `block_idx start from 0`, so the second loop also has an understandable condition (block_count?)

Comment: @JoopEggen Genius! That worked. Does strlen not include `\0`?

Comment: No, so a strdup allocates strlen + 1 chars

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem .  The current code fragment does not enable us to reproduce your code problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `traversed = 0;
while (traversed < block_idx) {` and `traversed++;`  Much more understandable to simply write: `for( int traversed=0; traversed < block_idx; traversed++ ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i <= len` as you want to deal with the terminating `\0` inside the loop. And better let `block_idx` start from 0, so the second loop also has an understandable condition (block_count?).

So: `strlen` returns the number of chars not including the terminating `\0`. Maybe better:

```
block = malloc((block_sizes[traversed] + 1) * sizeof(char));
block[block_sizes[traversed]] = '\0';
```